# Best way to do register a user in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to implement User Registration for my Django app.  The book I read mentions UserCreationForm but I need more than just name, password, and email address.  I could implement my own user object and use ModelForm I think, but then I lose out on some of the django conveniences for authentication.  Finally, I read something about UserProfiles which supplement Users I guess, so I think I need some combination of all of these things.  Here's what I have so far.

View - this is simple enough.  All I want to do here is create my form and save the user

```
def main(request):
    rform1 = forms.RegisterForm1()
    rform2 = forms.RegisterForm2()
    return render_to_response("authentication/index.html", {'form1': rform1, 'form2':rform2})

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        rform1 = forms.RegisterForm1(request.POST)
        rform2 = forms.RegisterForm2(request.POST)
        if rform1.is_valid() and rform2.is_valid():
            new_user = rform1.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/register-success/")
    return render_to_response("authentication/index.html", {'form1': rform1,'form2':rform2})
```

Form - this is my form for creating a user.  Or the start of it at least

```
class RegisterForm1(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User

class RegisterForm2(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
```

Model - this is my UserProfile that I want to supplement User with.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    phonenumber = PhoneNumberField()
```

Is it clear what I'm trying to do?  Am I on the right track

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/ubernostrum/django-registration

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Make *two* model forms, one for the `User` model and one for the `UserProfile` model.

```
class UserForm(django.forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User  

class UserProfileForm(django.forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ['user']
```

Give them prefixes and display them together in the same HTML form element.  In the view, check that both are valid before you save the User and then the UserProfile.

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uf = UserForm(request.POST, prefix='user')
        upf = UserProfileForm(request.POST, prefix='userprofile')
        if uf.is_valid() * upf.is_valid():
            user = uf.save()
            userprofile = upf.save(commit=False)
            userprofile.user = user
            userprofile.save()
            return django.http.HttpResponseRedirect(…something…)
    else:
        uf = UserForm(prefix='user')
        upf = UserProfileForm(prefix='userprofile')
    return django.shortcuts.render_to_response('register.html', 
                                               dict(userform=uf,
                                                    userprofileform=upf),
                                               context_instance=django.template.RequestContext(request))
```

In `register.html`:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{userform}}
    {{userprofileform}}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: The newest version of Django now requires a field attribute to be defined for every ModelForm

Answer (score 30):

I was just looking into this, and found out that Django has a very simple built-in new user creation form, which you can use if you want simple registration -- there's no option to, eg, save an email address and validate it, so it won't work for the OP's use case, but am posting it here in case other come across this question as I did, and are looking for something simple.

If you just want people to be able to choose a username and password, then **the built-ins will do everything for you**, including validation and saving the new user:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url('^register/', CreateView.as_view(
            template_name='register.html',
            form_class=UserCreationForm,
            success_url='/'
    )),
    url('^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),

    # rest of your URLs as normal
)
```

So the only thing you have to do yourself is create *register.html*...

More info here: http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/using-the-built-in-views-and-forms-for-new-user-registration-in-django.html

Comment: Any resources on how to create the register.html?

Comment: @Tunisia jsut create a template and render the `form` on it, just like for the login form example in the docs.