# Use pure HTML page for registration in Django

Tags: python, html, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-models

I am a Django newbie, so please go easy on me. I have the entire front-end of the website ready for use. I am writing back-end in Django. So, my homepage has a registration form and I want to register user using `Django-registration-redux`. What I don't understand is, is it necessary to use Django form to generate form and or I can simply use plain html with post data going to Django backend. The form looks like this:

```
<form role="form" id="user_form" method="post"
action="/appname/register" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if registered %}
        <strong>Thank you for registering! Check your email and confirm registration.
       </strong>
    {% else %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="register-username" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.68);font-weight: 500;">
                <i class="icon-user"></i>
                <b>Email</b>
            </label>
            <input class="form-control" id="register-username" type="text" placeholder="" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.68);font-weight: 500;">
            <label for="register-password">
                <i class="icon-lock"></i>
                <b>Password</b>
            </label>
            <input class="form-control" id="register-password" type="password" placeholder="" required>
        </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to use plain HTMLs in Django forms. In fact I think that is the most cases since the form system Django provides is simply not flexible enough.

1. You can try accessing the POST parameters directly. e.g.

   views.py:

   ```
   ...
   username = request.POST.get('username', '')
   password = request.POST.get('password', '')
   register(username, password)
   ...
   ```

   template.html

   ```
   <form action="/path" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="username"/>
     <input type="password" name="password"/>
   </form>
   ```

   Note that you may have to deal with CSRF tokens.
2. If you already have a Django form, e.g.

   ```
   class LoginForm(forms.Form):
       email = forms.EmailField(label="Email")
       password = forms.CharField(label="Password", max_length=255)
   ```

   you can just match the property names (e.g. email) with the name attribute in HTML forms. e.g.
   template.html

   ```
   <form action="/path" method="post">
     <input type="email" name="email"/>
     <input type="password" name="password"/>
   </form>
   ```

   then in your views.py, you can instantiate the form and access data in it with

   ```
   login_form = LoginForm(request.POST)
   email = login_form.cleaned_data['email']
   password = login_form.cleaned_data['password']
   login(email, password)
   ```

Comment: Can I use a variable ID in order to create a form that accepts data in bulk?

Answer (score 3):

You do not have to use [Django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/) whatsoever. You can handle the post variables at will in your `views.py`:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    # do something with request.POST
```

Nevertheless, I would recommend you to take advantage of the functionality that Django forms offer.

Comment: Thank you. Since, i already have front-end designed, I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Can you tell me how do I handle registration here in views? Sorry, I'm total newbie.

Comment: Welcome. I totally understand. You can still have django forms without rendering them, you just need to make sure that the names of `<input>` are sonsistent with the fields of the forms. For the registration, there are several good articles. Take a look at this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523745/best-way-to-do-register-a-user-in-django

Answer (score 2):

i guess you haven't mentioned the name attribute in input fields. If you don't want to use django form functionality, its all right. But remember to provide the name attributes in your form and they should have values equal to those defined in the model. For example, let's say my model is  class Post(models.Model):     title = models.CharField(max_length=100)       Then, in your form, you should declare an input field like this:

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can use pure HTML, as long as you give your input elements the `name` attributes that Django is expecting (you don't seem to have given them any names at all, so the form wouldn't even submit any data).

However, by doing this you are missing out on the ability to re-display the form with errors and partially-filled data when it fails to validate correctly. Since the only customization your fields appear to have is the addition of a "form-control" class, you might as well just make that change in the Django form.

Comment: Also, you miss an `{% endif %}`

Comment: Thanks, can you point out how do I convert this form to Django form? I have CSS defined for this form. How do I reutilize it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can always use a plain HTML form, as long as the input `name`s match what will be validated by your registration app.