# Django User Profile Model Sign Up Form

Tags: python, django

I'm developing django project.

Now I'm making sign up form with profile model.

But I got a problem.

models.py :

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    usernickname = models.CharField(db_column='userNickName', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    userbirth = models.DateField(db_column='userBirth', blank=True, null=True)  

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'profile'

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print(instance)
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

forms.py :

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    userBirth = forms.DateField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'userBirth')
        widgets = {
            'username': forms.TextInput(),
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(),
            'userBirth': forms.DateField(),
        }
```

views.py :

```
def join(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        userForm = UserForm(request.POST, prefix='user')
        profileForm = ProfileForm(request.POST, prefix='profile')
        if userForm.is_valid() * profileForm.is_valid():
            user = userForm.save()
            profile = profileForm.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user
            profile.save()

            return redirect('index')
    else:
        userForm = UserForm()
        profileForm = ProfileForm()
    return render_to_response('registration/join.html',dict(userform=userForm,
                                                profileform=profileForm))
```

and when sign up,

InternalError at /join/
(1054, "Unknown column 'profile.user_id' in 'field list'")

this error returns.

when log in to /admin,
same error returns. I don't have any idea..

I refernced this blog:

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html#sign-up-with-profile-model

Comment: have you tried adding this before user.save() "user.refresh_from_db() "

Comment: yes, i tried it.

Comment: you are saving a form then you are trying to create a new user why are you trying like this

Comment: Why are you doing `refresh_from_db` at all?

Comment: i tried many ways to solve and that code is one of them.. then what should i do?

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523745/best-way-to-do-register-a-user-in-django

Comment: It makes another error ㅠㅠ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have model profile - then add

db_column=${USER ID DB COLUMN NAME} on user field,

if no - set managed = True in Meta.

Also, you can use related_name='profile' to get profile instance from user.

Django tries to accept profile instance by user_id column, but can't identify it.

Comment: I have no idea where is user field you are talking. views.py ?

Answer (score 0):

in your forms.py in profile form I think you need to add 'user' field .